# Use mysql to work out in and out times of vehicle at customer, multiple stops and entries for each customer

Tags: mysql, max, min

I have a mysql table that contains data as per the screenshot below.

My requirement is to generate a mysql query that will show me the in and out time for each customer.
the issue I have is that I cannot use min or max as the vehicle might have visited the same customer two or three times within a period.

So the output I am looking for is:

```
Vehicle: RB10
Customer: Hulamin
In: 10:19
out: 10:35
Time Taken: 16 min
In: 11:14
out: 11:29
Time Taken: 15 min
ave time taken: 15.5 min
```

and the same for each of the other sites and vehicles as required.

How do I tell mysql to take the smallest in time before the corresponding out time and report?

Many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this question at http://www.doAllMyWorkForMe.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using SQL Variables to help control when the address changes, even IF they occur multiple times.  Without having MySQL readily available, I would approach something like below.  Start with an inner query that stamps a "GroupSeq" based on a change in either vehicle and/or address.  Keep the order sequential by date/time.  After each test against the @lastGroup is either left alone, or added 1 to the sequence, THEN update the @lastAddress and @lastVehicle as basis for the NEXT record being selected into the result set for comparison.

Per your example, the results of each customer would be (all these same vehicle, so not duplicating display of that column)
Address   GroupSeq
Hulamin   1
SACD      2
UL        3
NP        4
Hulamin   5
SACD      6

After that, you can then properly do your MIN/MAX based on the GroupSeq assigned.

```
select
      PreQuery.Vehicle,
      PreQuery.Address,
      PreQuery.GroupSeq,
      MIN( PreQuery.`DateTime` ) as InTime,
      MAX( PreQuery.`DateTime` ) as OutTime
   from
      ( select
              YT.Vehicle,
              YT.Address,
              YT.`DateTime`,
              YT.Direction,
              @lastGroup := @lastGroup + if( @lastAddress = YT.Address 
                                         AND @lastVehicle = YT.Vehicle, 0, 1 ) as GroupSeq,
              @lastVehicle := YT.Vehicle as justVarVehicleChange,
              @lastAddress := YT.Address as justVarAddressChange
           from
              YourTable YT,
              ( select @lastVehicle := '',
                       @lastAddress := '',
                       @lastGroup := 0 ) SQLVars
           order by
              YT.`DateTime` ) PreQuery
   Group By
      PreQuery.Vehicle,
      PreQuery.Address,
      PreQuery.GroupSeq
```

The above SHOULD result in something like

```
Vehicle   Address   GroupSeq   InTime   OutTime
RB10      Hulamin   1          10:19    10:35
RB10      SACD      2          10:37    10:40
RB10      UL        3          10:41    11:06
RB10      NP        4          11:07    11:14
RB10      Hulamin   5          11:14    11:28
RB10      SACD      6          11:29    12:21
```

Now, the above sample does not actually compute the total time taken per in-out, nor the average per vehicle/customer average time for what appears to be processing, but you can add those computations after you understand and get this part.

Please note, this is based on natural order as appears by date/time.  It looks like one transaction from beginning to end can have many "IN"s, but ALWAYS ends with an "OUT" before proceeding to the next customer address.  If this is an incorrect assumption, modifications would obviously need to be made.

Comment: Thanks Drapp, really really appreciate the effort you put into this answer. I need some time to digest it and learn from it so will feedback then. Many many thanks again, I had no idea where to start.

Comment: Think of the @ variables as an inline program.  the := is the assignment and whatever the results is stored into the final column for that row, but retain their value for the next cycle.  So, much like a loop of values in order, they get stamped per row.  Run the inner query by itself before the outer to see all the values.  Then, apply to the outer query to see final results.

Comment: Thanks again DRapp, appreciate your time. Will definately practice this. Cheers,

Comment: @RyanSmith, if you want to see one that can really make your head hurt... check out the link to this S/O thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057820/combining-monthly-futures-data-to-front-month-time-series-in-mysql/9089792#9089792

Comment: that one looks easy :-) I'll start with getting this one taped then do that one.